# Taking data from different Listbox entries to call a single function

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a program that uploads my grades and comments from google sheets and put them into D2L.

My goal is to have 3 or 4 list boxes that get populated from my google sheets, and use that information in a single function. The `print(l.get(cs))` as a place holder, it will eventually be used to call different tabs on my google sheet.

Right now I have to make each listbox call to `go()` `go1()` and `go2()`to make them work. Is there a way to make them all call `go()` and keep the data from the listbox?

```
from tkinter import *

gr7asgn=["7asgn1","7asgn2","7asgn3","7asgn4","7asgn5"]
gr8asgn=["8asgn1","8asgn2","8asgn3","8asgn4","8asgn5"]
gr9asgn=["9asgn1","9asgn2","9asgn3","9asg4n","9asgn5"]


def go():
    cs = l.curselection()[0]
    print(l.get(cs))

def go1():
    cs = l1.curselection()[0]
    print(l1.get(cs))

def go2():
    cs = l2.curselection()[0]
    print(l2.get(cs))

root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x300")
root.title("import comments")

#grade 7 list
l = Listbox(root, width=30, height=15, selectmode = EXTENDED)
l.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", lambda x: go())
for a in gr7asgn:
    l.insert(END,a)
l.grid(row=1,column=0)

#grade 8 list
l1= Listbox(root, width=30, height=15, selectmode = EXTENDED)
l1.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", lambda x: go1())
for a in gr8asgn:
    l1.insert(END,a)
l1.grid(row=1,column=1)

#grade 9 list
l2 = Listbox(root, width=30, height=15, selectmode = EXTENDED)
l2.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", lambda x: go2())
for a in gr9asgn:
    l2.insert(END,a)
l2.grid(row=1,column=2)
```

Comment: add Button which you will press after selecting elements in Listbox. This button should run function which get selections from all Listbox.

Comment: I will work on that, thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `Button` to run function which will get selected item from all `Listboxes` at once.

`Listbox` may need `exportselection=False` to keep value in `curselection()` when you click other listbox.

```
import tkinter as tk

gr7asgn=["7asgn1","7asgn2","7asgn3","7asgn4","7asgn5"]
gr8asgn=["8asgn1","8asgn2","8asgn3","8asgn4","8asgn5"]
gr9asgn=["9asgn1","9asgn2","9asgn3","9asg4n","9asgn5"]


def go():
    # TODO: check if curselection doesn't return empty list
    print('l1:', l1.curselection()[0], l1.get(l1.curselection()[0]))
    print('l2:', l2.curselection()[0], l2.get(l2.curselection()[0]))
    print('l3:', l3.curselection()[0], l3.get(l3.curselection()[0]))

root = tk.Tk()

# need `exportselection=False` to keep `curselection` when other listbox is clicked
l1 = tk.Listbox(root, exportselection=False)
l1.grid(row=1, column=0)
l1.insert('end', *gr7asgn) # put all items at once

l2 = tk.Listbox(root, exportselection=False)
l2.grid(row=1, column=1)
l2.insert('end', *gr8asgn)

l3 = tk.Listbox(root, exportselection=False)
l3.grid(row=1,column=2)
l3.insert('end', *gr9asgn)

b = tk.Button(root, text="Go", command=go)
b.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=3)

root.mainloop()
```

Doc: [Listbox](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm)